# Nexus 5 usb drivers on linux 64 bit

Tags: linux, usb, drivers, 64-bit

I can't make my Nexus 5 to be recognized by ADT to run apps on it. I already read discussions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20168898/nexus-5-usb-driver), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292692/installing-usb-driver-for-nexus-4-with-kitkat-on-windows-8-64-bit-no-compat) and also [this one](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) but none worked. I already have activated the developer mode. What can I do? I don't wanna to fracking wait till next march!
[sources](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/BA2QePyhees)

EDIT: I am on Debian Sid

Comment: Care to mention your linux distro?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the answer but is worth to give a try.

Try to not connect over `USB3` ports. Sounds weird but sometimes it only works with `USB2/USB1` ports at least on Linux side I don't know why.